# Get posts after today (upcoming events)

Tags: widgets

I'm using PHP Exec to build a widget to show a list of upcoming events:

```
<?php
function filter_whene($whene = '') {
    $whene .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "' ";
return $whene;
  }
add_filter('posts_whene', 'filter_whene');
query_posts('cat=10&showposts=3&');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><?php the_date(); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?>
  </a>  </li>
<?php endwhile;
else: ?><p>Não há eventos agendados.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php remove_filter('posts_whene', 'filter_whene'); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

It seems to work on the front end but I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare filter_whene() (previously declared in
>   /home/content/a/c/a/acamorg/html/cea2/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42)
>   : eval()'d code:3) in
>   /home/content/a/c/a/acamorg/html/cea2/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42)
>   : eval()'d code on line 6

on the widget back-end.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@user2816:**

It would seem you are using that code in more than one widget?  Try changing part of that code from these:

```
function filter_whene($whene = '') {
  $whene .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "' ";
  return $whene;
}
add_filter('posts_whene', 'filter_whene');
```

To this:

```
if (!function_exists('filter_whene')) {
  function filter_whene($whene = '') {
    $whene .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d') . "' ";
    return $whene;
  }
}
add_filter('posts_whene', 'filter_whene');
```

Better, move as much of your code as possible to your theme's `functions.php` file. Wrap it in a function and then you only have to type one line of code in your PHP Exec widget.

Or better yet, **get rid of that plugin completely and [write your own widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets)**; *because PHP Exec is* ***evil***.

P.S. Okay, PHP Exec is not evil *per se*, but once you try to do anything more than trivial it creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! I'm not using the code in more than one widget and yes, I had already looked for Exec PHP alternatives, as I'm always wary that will break something that I won't know how to fix. Your "create your own widget" suggestion is perfect, of course!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answered your question. I use this snippet on my sidebar, to get future posts:

```
<ul>
<?php
query_posts('post_status=future&order=asc&orderby=date');
//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  echo "<li>";
  echo the_date();
  echo "<br />";
  echo the_title();
  echo"</li>";
endwhile; else:
   echo "<li>there's no future post at the moment.</li>";
endif;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I already went through the "post_status=future" solution (and a meta_value Date one). But then non logged in users could not see the related post. Meta_value would not (I know from experience) be very user friendly. I now use "Future is Now" plugin (which invalidates the future posts solution, as all upcoming events will have a published state), and the above piece of code. I don't need to schedule future posts, so this is the right solution for me.